# Cast/replace to increase column length

Tags: sql, sql-server, maxlength

In moving data from one table to another in SQL Server/Vertica, I am running into a string octet length error:

> String of 11 octets is too long for type char(10)

When I insert data from table1 to table2, can I simply use a `cast(replace(column1) as char(50))` to increase column length?

Comment: I think the destination column is too small to accommodate the data from your old one.. so to speak. You can either choose to trim the column data to fit the new column or increase the destination column width to accommodate the original data

Comment: It would be helpful to see a little more code.  It sounds like table2 already exists and already has a destination column that is too small.  But, it's hard to tell from just a description.

Comment: correct- table2 already exists with limited destination column.

Answer (score 1):

Your destination column is too long.  That suggests that you want:

```
left(column1, 10)
```

Or you want to fix the column in the destination table:

```
alter table destination alter column column1 varchar(255);
```

Or whatever.